# "selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: Unsupported locator strategy" error while interacting with canvas tool on a page in Selenium

Tags: canvas, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting the following Selenium error while interacting with a canvas element on a page:

> selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: Unsupported
>   locator strategy: Null

I have verified the Chrome version and Chrome driver version. Both are same.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade chromedriver version.
I had same issue with ChromeDriver 77.0.3865.40, but everything ok with ChromeDriver 77.0.3865.10